# How to bring down variables from JavaScript to Classic ASP - GeoCoding

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I want to be able to pass the requested information LAT, LONG, and AddressField to an ASP textfield box so I can use these results in another asp page.

I am able to get LAT and LONG to complete in a textboxes and pass this information over.

I cannot get the address to populate.

There is currently a default address field that contains a default location. It will also allow the users to enter in an address.

On `submit` the code returns the Geocoding info to the same page.

I can get the LAT and LONG to fill in but I am unable to get the address to populate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <style>


  </style>

  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API KEY & 
 sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function () {
      // find DOM elements
      var latField = document.getElementById('lat');
      var lngField = document.getElementById('long');
      var canvas = document.getElementById('map');
      var form = document.getElementById('addressForm');
      var addressField = form.address;

      // create map, marker, infowindow and geocoder objects
      var options = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.9611755, -82.99879420000002),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, options);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map
      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

      // set handler for form.onsubmit event
      form.onsubmit = function () {
        return showAddressOnMap(addressField.value);
      }

      // worker function to display marker on map at address
      function showAddressOnMap(address) {
        try {
          var geocoderRequest = {
            address: address
          }
          geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              var location = results[0].geometry.location;
              map.setCenter(location);
              marker.setPosition(location);
              var content = [];
              content.push('<strong>' + results[0].formatted_address +
                '</strong>');
              content.push('Lat: ' + location.lat());
              content.push('Lng: ' + location.lng());
              infowindow.setContent(content.join('<br/>'));
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
              latField.value = location.lat();
              lngField.value = location.lng();
            }
          });
          return false;
        } catch (e) {
          return false; //ensure form does not submit, even if there's an error
        }
      }
    };

  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map" style="width:500px;height:350px;border:1px solid #999;"></div>
  <form id="addressForm" style="margin:10px 0;">
    <input name="address" size="69" value="Columbus, Ohio"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <div style="font-family:'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form id="addressForm" name="address" method="post" action="test9.asp"> Address
    <label for="address"></label>
    <input name="address" type="text" id="address" size="69" />
    <p>
      <p>Lat
        <label for="lat"></label>
        <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" />
      </p>
    </p>
    <p>Long
      <label for="Long"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Long" id="Long" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have two forms with `id="addressForm"`, but the second one is missing an opening `<`. Also, what's with the empty labels?

Comment: That was a typeO the < didn't come across.. What are you referring to as empty labels? If you are referring to Lat and Long  they are being populated when the user enters in the address and clicks the first submit. The address is then submit for geocoding to google and returns the lat and long and fills in the lat and long so it can be submitted to another page. this works but I cannot figure how to get the address to pass over to the second addressform field or if I am doing this right. This is what I need help with.

Comment: Fixed your typo referred to in comment and formatted your code. I don't know what you are asking for help with but a basic idea, already pointed out to you by **@Martha** is having two elements with the same name is asking for trouble. How about `addressForm1` and `addressForm2` if you can't think of any better names. How many different things do you want to call `address`? Even if it makes no difference to the machine it will make it easier for humans (including you) to read your code.

Comment: Thanks I got the solution to work.